# Como enviar notificaciones push de firebase desde una app android a una app iOS y viceversa?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, ios, swift

Tengo actualmente una app de chat tanto en android(java) como en iOS(swift) y ambas funcionan con la misma base de datos en Firebase. necesito ayuda para configurar las notificaciones push ya que lo he intentado y nada.

Si envio un mensaje con un usuario android a un usuario iOS no llega la notificacion y lo mismo ocurre en caso contrario.

Actualmente solo me funcionan las notificaciones de android a android.

en iOS ya tengo configurados los certificados necesarios de apple y el proyecto firebase

necesito de su apoyo.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y dónde quedó el código?

Comment: Te funcionan las notificaciones de un dispositivo iOS a otro iOS?

Comment: Hola, es importante agregar lo que haz realizado para tener una idea de donde puede estar el problema, revisa [ask], edita tu pregunta agregando más información, saludos.